# This is undefined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

SO here is my route.js file, which handles all the routes.

```
// Import post controller
const PostController = require('../controllers/post');

// Call post controller for API
router.post('/posts', PostController.create);
```

And then there is post.js file in controllers, which exports Post class.

```
const PostModel = require('../models/post');

class Post 
{
    async create ()
    {
        response = {};

        let posts = await PostModel.find({});

        response.additionalInfo = this.getAdditionalInfo();

        res.status(200).send({response});
    }

    getAdditionalInfo ()
    {
        // returns some data for users and something
    }
}

module.exports = new Post();
```

Now My question is how do i call `getAdditionalInfo()` from create method? because if i try `this.getAdditionalInfo()` i get `undefined` error.

This is how `create` is being used:

```
router.post('/posts', PostController.create);
```

Comment: I get :- Invalid status code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAdditionalInfo' of undefined

Because `this` is undefined.

Comment: router.post('/posts', PostController.create);

Comment: No need to use this keyword, just call getAdditionalInfo() and check.

Comment: @Sudharshan, Then i get :- 
Invalid status code: ReferenceError: getAdditionalInfo is not defined

Comment: You didn’t define a constructor method, so the interpreter substituted the default one which does nothing.

Comment: @VorpalSword,
Then how do i achieve this in my scenario?

Comment: https://javascript.info/class is a good tutorial on using js's class syntax

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With your

```
router.post('/posts', PostController.create);
```

, `router.post` is accepting a function named `create` *as a callback*. This means that when it's invoked, for example, if the internal code for `router.post` looks something like this:

```
(url, callback) => {
  on(someevent, () => {
    callback();
  });
}
```

The calling context is missing. It's not calling `PostController.create()`, it's just calling `someCallbackVariableName()`. So, without a calling context, the `this` inside of `create` is `undefined` as a result.

Instead, either pass a function that *invokes* `create` with the proper calling context:

```
router.post('/posts', () => PostController.create());
```

Or use `.bind` to explicitly set the calling context to `PostController`:

```
router.post('/posts', PostController.create.bind(PostController));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it so easily. :)

Comment: How would we use paramters in this example?  outer.post('/posts', PostController.create(param1).bind(PostController));  ??

Comment: @johnktejik Pass a function which calls `.create` with the right arguments.  `router.post('/posts', () => PostController.create(param1));`